# JQUERY - modify var in a function and other function find this modification

Tags: jquery, click, var

I'm trying to modify a var in a function and the other function find this modification

the sketch:

function
click element -> var = 0
click other element -> var = 1

function

if var = 1 do stuff
if var = 0 do not this stuff

thx for your help

Comment: Use a variable that's in a scope that both functions can see -  possibly global. What have you tried, and what are you struggling with?

Comment: you can set input type hidden on the click of he clickable element and use value from that hidden input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stat = 0;  // here stat is global

$('.some1').on('click',
    function() {
        stat = 1;
        doSomething(stat);
    });
$('.some2').on('click',
    function() {
        stat = 0;
        doSomething(stat);
    });
function doSomething() {
    if (stat == 1) { 
        $('body').append('<div class="newadded">Something happen</div>');
    } else {
        $('body').remove('div.newadded');
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i'm not very good in english.
I want to when i click on .some1 it's adding some features to my page, but when i click on .some2 it's remove these features, it's becoming to the start

Comment: I suggest you to study more javascript and jQuery, it really isn't that hard if you put your efforts on it. The answer of @theCodeParadox do exactly what you asked, the function another is the one that manages what happens if stat = 1, if stat = 0, it will simply skip the function, if you need something special for it use else if(stat == 0) { //Do something } remember to use "==" that is equal to operator, "=" is to bind variable to value.